# notification , Server to Client

Tags: android, cakephp

I was developing an android app and a server that serve this apps. The server was coded in cakePHP. I want the app to have a notification from the server when there is an update on whatever things. Is this notification function a Server to client connection ? For example the facebook , whatapps and other social app in smart phone that could receive notification when someone send you a message, tagged you etc.

What is the proper way of doing this? I just need an idea to start. I see someone suggesting to open a long establish connection from client to check whether there is an update, but this would drain the phone battery.

If it's a Server to client connection, how would the server know where to find the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google cloud messaging would seem to be the best option here; https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

As it says on the tin; "*Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device, and also to receive messages from devices on the same connection*"

xtify seems to also support what you are asking but I've no experience with it.

Although depending on your particular requirements there are other options available.

If the client only needs to get notifications when active you could have it check the server every X number of seconds for updates when it is not asleep or even when the user does a particular action. Of course this all depends on what you want to happen.

edit: Heres a good article/tutorial with code samples https://blog.serverdensity.com/android-push-notifications-tutorial/

Comment: No problem. If you hit any more issues just ask.